# Do there exist $a(x),b(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ s.t. $(x^4+4x^3-7x+2)a(x)+(x^2+3x-4)b(x)=x^2+1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove or disprove the following:
>
> There exist $a(x), b(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x)=x^2+1$, where
> $f(x)=x^4+4x^3-7x+2$ , $g(x)=x^2+3x-4$.

It looks very much like Bezout's identity, although $\gcd(f,g)\ne x^2+1$, so I can't use it. ($\gcd(f,g)=x-1$)

Comment: **Hint** The sum of the coef's of both poly's is $0$ so they both have root $x=1,$ which is not a root of RHS; equivalently eval at $x=1$ yields $0 = 2\ \ $

Comment: Generally, by Bezout, there are $a,b\in F[x]$ with $\, af+bg = h\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid h\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done most of the work

Consider $\gcd(f,g)=x-1$

This means that $f(x)=(x-1)(F(x))$ and similarly $g(x)=(x-1)(G(x))$.

We can substitute this into the equation

$$(x-1)(a(x)F(x)+b(x)G(x))=x^2+1$$

But $x-1$ does not divide $x^2+1$

Comment: A shorter way to prove (still using the fact that $x-1$ divides $f(x)$ and $g(x)$) is to substitute $x$ by $1$, where you would obtain $0=2$ as a contradiction.

Comment: that works but thats essentially the same as proving that $x-1\mid x^2+1$ is false